# How can I keep a record of my faulty tools in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of my tools, their features, make, model etc. And to the right of it I have a popup box stating their instant status as "faulty" and "okay". When I mark the tool as faulty, I want it to keep a record with the date and time on another page. The list needs to be added one after the other, because when I look back, I want to see how many times a device has failed. When I change it from tool faulty to okay, it should not be deleted from the list, but the okay date should be added.

My pages are "Tool List" and "Fault List".

[Tool List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJI0C.png)

I was try a lot of things, I ask the chatgpt and bard but doesn't work any code.

Comment: You need `AppScript` coding. Formula can't do that.

Comment: Yes I know, I asked chatgpt and bard they create some appscript codes but didn't work

Comment: "You need AppScript coding." `Yes I know`. You have described a complex system that you "want" to develop. However StackOverflow is not a bespoke scripting service. Users are keen to assist YOU to solve a problem, but not necessarily solve the problem for you. ChatGPT is completely unreliable as a source of solutions, so it does not count as research. Would you please explain what, EXACTLY, is your problem?